# How can I get a character coordinates by parsing the bytes of a file?

Tags: localization, hex, byte, hexdump

I want to localize a game, and the font is made of a DDS file containing the drawings of the characters, and a file containing the coordinates to the drawings in the DDS file. I hope this is clear :<. So, the problem is IDK how to edit or parse the bytes to get these coordinates

In this link you'll find all files you need.
1- the coordinates files ending with .blb
2- the DDS files ending with DDS ('duh')
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BoXNBj7yYJHsS6juHdQsiZ4NQr1Yyew_?usp=sharing

I know for a fact that the blb files are indeed the coordinates files because I edited them with a HEX editor and some of the characters got missed up. Also, in the same google drive link you can find text file for the magic header or whatever it's called. Thank you for reading :).

[A screenshot showing affected characters after messing with the file with a hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YSdT.jpg)